# Combining users on OSX 10.6.8

Tags: macos, user-account

I just bought a new mac and when migrating my old to my new mac, I accidentally put it in a different user. Is there a way, I can combine both users?

Comment: If you can list a subset of the data you want to combine, that might be more workable than the general "combine everything" which isn't feasable.

Comment: @bmike - applications, documents and settings

Comment: You can re-run the assistant to move applications as they exist in /Applications. Any documents and settings can be moved to the new desktop. Settings are harder since you can choose one finder setting - the old or the new, not just merge them. Apps from ~/Applications can be copied easily. Settings are from ~/Library/Preferences mostly. Some like sync Dara are stored elsewhere in ~/Library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to combine user accounts. If one of the accounts is empty the best option is to delete it. Otherwise, move everything you want from one account's home folder to another and then get rid of the old one.